# Image Displays Incorrectly On All Versions Of Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript

I have the following Javascript code that resizes images on a page:

```
    var max_size = 498;
    $(".slideimage").each(function(i) {
      if ($(this).height() > $(this).width()) {
        var h = max_size;
        var w = Math.ceil($(this).width() / $(this).height() * max_size);
      } else {
        var w = max_size;
        var h = Math.ceil($(this).height() / $(this).width() * max_size);
      }
      $(this).css({ height: h, width: w });
    });
```

This code is contained within a $(document).ready() function.

The images display fine when viewed in Chrome, Firefox, Safari and Opera. However, when the same page is viewed in Internet Explorer 7, 8 and 9, sometimes (well, 50% of the time) when the page is first loaded the image appears at the correct width, but the height is really really small. I would guesstimate the height to be around 100px high. But when the page is reloaded, the same image will display perfectly.

It's a strange issue, and only happens in IE. Do I need to add or remove anything in that code?

Cheers

Comment: Maybe you could insert `alert("height: " + h + ", width: " +w);` into the line before `$(this).css({ height: h, width: w });` to see, if the problem is in the code or in the rendering.

Comment: I've added that code in, and in Chrome it returns correct values. In IE, the images haven't messed up yet. I am keeping the code there for the time being, and keeping reloading/refreshing the page to see the error.

Comment: @mickburkejnr: try loading the page with an empty cache and see what values you get. If you're checking the width/height too early e.g when the image (or at least its header which contains information about the image dimensions) is not loaded then you'll get wrong values. Actually, this may also be the case with other browsers as well.

Comment: I've moved the javascript to the footer and the error still happens.

Answer (score 2):

document.ready() potentially occurs before all of the images have been loaded on a page, so the reported height and width can be 0 or, as in your case, 100.

You need to wait for the page's images to be loaded before you can find their sizes reliably, particularly on IE.

Comment: I had exact same problem. Once possible workaround is to add `width=""` and `height=""` attributes on your `<img>` tags. Otherwise older versions of IE will report a width and height of 32px if the image is not in the cache and needs downloading (remember the image download placeholder icon?). Modern versions of IE may report 0.